# CanCanCan authorize associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, cancan

My Routes.rb:

```
resources :users
resources :clients do
  resources :branches
end
```

I have this in Ability.rb. User can update only his own clients.

```
  can [:update], Client, :id => user.clients.pluck(:id)
```

User should be also able to :create, :update, :show branches which belong to client. It might look somehting like this:

```
  can [:create, :update, :show], Branch, :client => { :id => user.clients.pluck(:id) }
```

It works for :update, :show, but not for :create. It's because new Branch doesn't have client_id before create.
How do I make it work for :create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current ability is actually not calling a check on the foreign key field on branch. Using nesting like that is calling the equivalent of `client.id` instead of `client_id` like you want.

Should read:

`can [:create, :update, :show], Branch, client_id: user.client_ids`

or, staying consistent with your style:

`can [:create, :update, :show], Branch, client_id: user.clients.pluck(:id)`